# UIActivityViewController send UIImage

Tags: swift, uiimage, uiactivityviewcontroller

I have one image generate it in App

the image displayed in uiimageview

here is my  image

```
var img:UIImage!
img = UIImage(ciImage: transformedImage)
```

here is the value before share it in breakpoint

```
print(img)
```

some(UIImage: 12345 , {200, 200})

```
let myShare = "My beautiful photo! <3 <3"


let shareVC: UIActivityViewController = UIActivityViewController(activityItems: [(img), myShare], applicationActivities: nil)
self.present(shareVC, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

but the image can not be show but the text it's show in iMessage or email and other apps ...  How can I share the image ? in iMessage emails and etc...

Answer (score 0):

Use this method:

```
func shareImageBtn(img : UIImage, txt : String) {
// if an image and a txt aren't nil
        let resourses = [ image!, txt!]
        let activityViewController = UIActivityViewController(activityItems: resources, applicationActivities: nil)
        activityViewController.popoverPresentationController?.sourceView = self.view // iPads won't crash

        // (optional)
        activityViewController.excludedActivityTypes = [ .airDrop, .postToFacebook ]

        // present the VC
        self.present(activityViewController, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }
```